# Derive Peano Axioms from Properties of the Natural Numbers

Tags: reference-request, peano-axioms

It is well-known that, beginning from Peano's axioms and the usual rules of logic, one can derive all the properties of the natural numbers, and beyond, up to the complex numbers. See Landau's [*Foundations of Analysis*](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~lipman/503/foundations-of-analysis.pdf) for the details.

What I am interested in is the reverse direction, and here it's not so much getting from the complexes to Peano. It would be sufficient for my purposes just to get from the properties of the natural numbers to the Peano axioms.

I have taken a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201077/can-we-prove-the-peano-axioms-from-a-type-theoretic-construction-of-the-natural), but as I am not an expert in foundations, this answer is beyond me (I'm looking for something on the level of Landau, actually). I'm also not sure it's really what I'm asking.

> So, to be specific, I would like to know if, from this set of axioms (or a suitably altered set of axioms):
>
> 1. **Closure:** For all natural numbers $a$ and $b,$ $a+b$ is a natural number.
> 2. **Commutativity:** For all natural numbers $a$ and $b,$ $a+b=b+a$ and $ab=ba.$
> 3. **Associativity:** For all natural numbers $a,b,$ and $c,$ $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$ and $(ab)c=a(bc).$
> 4. **Identities:** There exist natural numbers $0$ and $1$ such that $a+0=a$ and $a\cdot 1=a$ for all natural numbers $a.$
> 5. **Distributive:** For all natural numbers $a,b,$ and $c,$ $a(b+c)=ab+ac.$
> 6. **No Nonzero Divisors:** For all natural numbers $a,b,$ if $ab=0,$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0.$
>
> we can derive the Peano axioms (slightly modified from Landau to include $0$):
>
> P.1. $0$ is a natural number.
>
> P.2. For each natural number $x,$ there exists exactly one number, called the successor of $x,$ which will be denoted by $x'.$
>
> P.3. We always have $x'\not=0.$
>
> P.4. If $x'=y',$ then $x=y.$
>
> P.5. Let there be given a set $M$ of natural numbers with the following properties:
>      a. $0$ belongs to $M.$
>      b. If $x$ belongs to $M,$ then so does $x'.$ Then $M$ contains all the natural numbers.

I'm also interested to know if we can weaken the first list of axioms above. Do we need closure? No non-zero divisors? Distributive law?

**My Thoughts:**

P.1 seems obvious, given Axiom 4. P.2, it seems to me, would need to be derived from the '$+1$' operation, which is well-defined given Axioms 1 and 4. I'm fairly sure, if you did that, P.4 would be fairly straight-forward. P.3 and P.5 seem difficult.

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: I feeling like something is missing... Did You try $Z_5$ or some other finite commutative ring? it seems for like all 1-6 are true there, but successor of some element still can be zero.

Comment: @guest: But then, would "No Nonzero Divisors" still be true? Maybe so - it's a multiplicative group of prime order. What should we add?

Comment: Prime order is perfectly ok - the ring of integers modulo prime number becomes a  finite field. What I mean is that not all P1-P5 can be derived -- I suspect finite fields have all 1-6 properties but not all P1-P5, e.g. there exists at least one algebraic structure (finite field) that violates the statement "P1-P5 follow from 1-6", thus the latter cannot be proven.

Comment: @guest: Gotcha. So how should we strengthen the listed axioms to prove all of P1-P5? Preferably in a minimal way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way to avoid some kind of induction axiom.  Note in particular that you definiitely need some axiom that is not first-order.

Comment: So, what would you propose, in particular?

Comment: Well as soon as you have induction you basically have the Peano axioms already, so I don't know what you would consider satisfying.

Comment: In particular, your talk about "properties of the natural numbers" strikes me as rather odd.  The Peano axioms are _also_ properties of the natural numbers.  So given that you say you aren't wedded to your specific list of axioms, it's very unclear _which_ properties of the natural numbers you consider to be "fair" to use.

Comment: I guess, there is no other way than joining P3 or some equivalent statement to 1-6. Consider the following: integers and natural numbers in terms of + and $\cdot$ have the same properties. The only difference is that You cannot get $0$ by adding natural numbers. Thus You should state this property explicitly, otherwise integers will be an option and -1 + 1 = 0, thus P3 violated.

Comment: @guest: Do you agree with Eric that you'd have to add an induction axiom?

Comment: I'm not sure because induction may perfectly work on integers, then why should it prevent us from having $-1$ in our "number system"? Moreover, if we always start induction from $0$ it "cannot see" negative numbers at all, why should it forbid us using negative numbers? My intuition says no, induction will not be very helpful.

Comment: My view of the problem is as follows: consider natural numbers and integers. They both have properties 1-6, but You don't want both of them, You need natural numbers only. Thus, You should find some property that distinguishes $N$ from $Z$ and You'll have a good chance that this property will extract You $N$ out of all the possible algebraic systems. Which exact property? Honestly, I have no idea. Maybe something like "$a+b=0$ means $a=0$ and $b=0$", i.e. additive dual of 6.

Comment: Distinguishing $\mathbb{N}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial and there are loads of ways to do it (your suggestion works, and so do many others).  But there are way more possibilities allowed by the axioms than just integers: for instance, the nonnegative reals also satisfy 1-6 and $a+b=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$.  More generally, any set of first-order axioms is always going to allow uncountable models by Lowenheim-Skolem.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: Positive reals are a very good example -- I like it. It unleashes the fact that numbers in P1-P5 are generated by means of $x+1$ operation, while 1-6 say nothing on the "supply" of numbers we are intended to use. But I still have some feeling we can do something. What about demanding a system to be the smallest one? I.e. say there should exist no such other "number system" for which 1-6 are true and it is isomorhic to any subset of the chosen one.

Comment: I've got a hunch: we need the smallest infinite number system that satisfies 1-6. Intuitively: infinitness wipes out all finite fields. Since the system should be the smallest one (e.g. no other system satifying 1-6 isomophic to subsystem of the current one and not isomorhic to it whole), we can safely remove numbers before zero (P3). To get P5 we just collect everything we can get starting from 0 and doing +1 to get M and than show that M satisfies 1-6, e.g. cannot be "part" of the smallest system. I know this is very unrigorous (intuition only), but this way looks quite promising as for me.